# Is it ok to rewrite unit test in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, qunit

Recently I started unit testing JavaScript app I'm working on. No matter if I use Jasmine,QUnit or other I always write set of tests. Now, I have my source code with lets say:

```
function calc()
{
    // some code
    someOtherFunction();
    // more code
}
```

I also have a test (no matter what framework, with Jasmine spies or sinon.js or something) that confirms that `someOtherFunction()` is called when `calc()` is executed. Test passes. Now at some point I refactor the calc function so the `someOtherFunction()` call doesn't exist e.g.:

```
function calc()
{
    // some code
    someVariable++;
    // more code
}
```

The previous test will fail, yest the function still will function as expected, simply its code is different.

Now, I'm not sure if I understand correctly how testing is done. It seems obvious that I will have to go back and rewrite the test but if this happens is there something wrong with my approach? Is it bad practice? If so at which point I went wrong.

Comment: if the behavior of your function is still correct, then your test is wrong. But your test apparently tests that `someOtherFunction` is called. Which it is not. It therefore appears that your definition of `good behavior` on which you built your test is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is you don't test implementation details. So given you decided that it was okay to remove the call, the method was an implementation detail and therefore you should not have tested that it was called.

20/20 hindsight is  great thing is n't it?

In general I wouldn't test that a 'public' method called a 'private' one. Testing delegation should be reserved for when one class calls another.

Answer (score 0):

You have written a great unit test.

The unit tests should notice sneaky side-effects when you change the implementation.
And the test must fail when the expected values don't show up.

So look to your unit test where the expected value don't match and decide what was the problem:
1) The unit test tested things it shouldn't (change the test)
2) The code is broken (add the missing side-effect)

Comment: No, not sarcasm.  
A good unit test will check changes in your function calc() and
tell you when the changes are no longer downwards compatible.
You think that someOtherFunction(); could be replaced without
changing the api of calc().  
Now it seems that someOtherFunction(); changes some counter/global var you have forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to rewrite this test. A lot of tests fail to be perfect on the first pass. The most common test smell is tight-coupling with implementation details.

Your unit test should verify the behavior of the object, not how it achieved the result. If you're strict about doing this in a tdd style, maybe you should revert the code you changed and refactor the test first. But regardless of what technique you use, it's fine to change the test as long as you're decoupling it from the details of the system under test.